# Hacer un filtro php mysql con distintas tablas

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli

buanas amigos, estoy tratando de hacer un filtro para elementos que se encuentren en mi base de datos pero en distintas tablas.

he logrado hacer que me traiga los valores de una tabla "sede" pero quiero agregarle una que solo me muestre los valores de los usuarios que estan solamente en esa sede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he leido algo que con un join se puede hacer pero algunos que he visto tardan muchisimo en ejecutarse y aun no entiendo por que .

asi estoy haciendo mis busquedas mediante php

```
function listUser($conexion){

    $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre
                                          FROM sede as p
                                          //luego de la busqueda , el orden   
                                          ORDER BY p.nombre ASC")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $consulta;
}
```

la tabla sede tiene un id que ya me trae el nombre de los elementos que alli estan pero como lo que se me dificulta es anexar el siguiente campo segun sea el primer resultado...
gracias

el filtro constaria de 3 tablas
sucursal ,usuario ,departamento

sede : id , nombre
usuario : id, id_persona, id_departamento,nombre y clave
departamento: id , id_sede, nombre

Comment: omitan lo de "personanombre"

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu publicación y mostrar las estructuras de tus tablas, ya que de esa forma te podremos decir, si para mostrar los datos que requieres necesitas realizar un inner join o simplemente poner una condición.

Comment: voy @EduardoJavierMaldonado